# PHP: Update objects array values with another unsorted objects array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two objects arrays.

First array `$x`:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 54
        [value] => test54
        [something] => testtest54
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 21
        [value] => test21
        [something] => testtest21
    )
...
```

Second array `$y`:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 21
        [value] => test21_new_value
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 54
        [value] => test54_new_value
    )
...
```

I want to update my first array `$x` importing `value` of the second array's (`$y`) field which has the same `id`, I want to have :

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 54
        [value] => test54_new_value
        [something] => testtest54
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 21
        [value] => test21_new_value
        [something] => testtest21
    )
...
```

I can do something like this :

```
foreach($x as $k => $v) {
    foreach($y as $k2 => $v2) {
        if ($v->id === $v2->id) $x[$k]->value = $v2->value;
    }
}
```

But I don't like this, because I have to walk on array `$y` for each `$x` (if I have 100 items in `$x` and 100 items in `$y`, it loops 100*100 times). I think there is a more efficient, elegant or optimized way to do this, but I don't know how to do that (I did not found a precise response to this specific problem, so I ask here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Usually you'd use an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) for this (with the key being the unique ID), as this would mean (100 + 100) iterations instead of (100 * 100):

```
<?php
    $assocX = array();
    foreach ($x as $v) {
        $assocX[$v->id] = $v;
    }

    foreach ($y as $v) {
        $v->something = $assocX[$v->id]->something;
    }
?>
```

If you can't be sure that the value exists in `$x` you can also check for this ("no value" would be translated to `NULL`):

```
<?php
    $assocX = array();
    foreach ($x as $v) {
        $assocX[$v->id] = $v;
    }

    foreach ($y as $v) {
        $v->something = (isset($assocX[$v->id]) ? $assocX[$v->id]->something : null);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ! Actually, the `&` isn't necessary with objects arrays, I think. $v already is a reference to an object (I've just tried with one loop, but maybe I'm wrong or I don't understood)

Comment: @rap-2-h You're right. Objects are always passed by reference (forgot that - it's late-ish!) :)